# Default ScrollingOffset for mouse-wheel-changes

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, user-interface

I have an input form that I have to scroll based on changes of the mouse-wheel. I can not use the standard mechanic to let the scrolling be done automatically but have to do the scrolling manually (from code).

My question is, if there are some guidelines or standards on how big the scrolling offsets should be? Maybe there exists an enumeration (.net) that holds default-values? The contents that is shown are huge input forms. (The app is a WPF-App, however I assume this is a general question that is independent of the language)

**Update**

Thanks to gstercken showing me the appropriate value in the SystemInformation-class, I have found for WPF the `System.Windows.SystemParameters.WheelScrollLines` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SystemInformation` class has a property `MouseWheelScrollLines` that indicates how many *logical lines* to scroll for every notch of the mouse wheel (set by the user in the Mouse control panel), or -1 if the "One screen at a time" mouse option is selected.

However, it is up to your specific application what should be regarded as a "logical line".